# Why the onsubmit doesnt work and if I call the function in the console it runs?

Tags: javascript, html, web, webforms

I have this html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="js/filename.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id = "dp5" action=""  method="POST" onsubmit="Write_Text()">
      <h3>5- Do you know any browsers?</h3>
      <input id = "No" type="radio" name="dp5N" value="false">
      <label for = "No">No </label>

      <input id = "yes" type="radio" name="dp5S" value="true">
      <label for = "yes">Yes</label>

      <label for = "text">6 - Which?</label>
      <input id = "text" type="text" name="dp5text" value="">
    </form>

    <div id="next">
      <input id="sub" type="submit" name="submit" value="Next">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this javascript "filename":

```
function Write_Text() {
let x = document.forms["dp5"]["No"].value;

if (x === "false") {
    document.getElementById("text").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("text").value="";
} else {
    document.getElementById("text").disabled =false;
}
```

}

The text box should start disabled and only be able when the user choose "yes" option. The function isn't working at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your submit button is outside the form. Put it inside the form and it will work.

```
<form id = "dp5" action=""  method="POST" onsubmit="Write_Text(); return false">
  <h3>5- Do you know any browsers?</h3>
  <input id = "No" type="radio" name="dp5N" value="false">
  <label for = "No">No </label>

  <input id = "yes" type="radio" name="dp5S" value="true">
  <label for = "yes">Yes</label>

  <label for = "text">6 - Which?</label>
  <input id = "text" type="text" name="dp5text" value="">

  <div id="next">
    <input id="sub" type="submit" name="submit" value="Next">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Well, it won't work such much as it will fail in a different way. :-) See my (now) community wiki answer for why and what to do about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53187046/157247

Comment: Ah.. forgot about preventing the default behaviour of the form. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Once you fix [the problem Sreekanth MK pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53187092/157247), you'll have a new problem:

Nothing is preventing the default action of the form submission, which is to send the form data to the `action` URL (in your case it will be the page's own URL) and **replace** the current page with whatever that URL returns.

You need to prevent the default action. The minimal way is:

```
<form id = "dp5" action=""  method="POST" onsubmit="Write_Text(); return false">
```

or

```
<form id = "dp5" action=""  method="POST" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); Write_Text();">
```

...but I recommend using modern event handling instead by removing the `onsubmit` attribute and changing the JavaScript like this:

```
function Write_Text(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let x = document.forms["dp5"]["No"].value;

    if (x === "false") {
        document.getElementById("text").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("text").value="";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("text").disabled =false;
    }
}
document.getElementById("dp5").addEventListener("submit", Write_Text);
```

Note that you need to move your `script` tag. Putting `script` in `head` is an anti-pattern. Scripts go [at the end of the page](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom), right before the closing `</body>` tag.

---

Side note: You're free to do anything you like in your own code, but FWIW, the **overwhelming** convention in JavaScript is that function names start with a lower case letter and use `camelCase`, other than constructors which used initially-capped `CamelCase` instead. So `writeText` rather than `Write_Text`.

Comment: I'll post it, the bug

Comment: @AdathSkyderson - The last one works just fine if your `script` is in the right place (at the end of `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag).

Comment: I have a .js file

Comment: @AdathSkyderson - It doesn't matter whether it's a separate file or inline script. What matters is the location of the `script` tag relative to the elements it operates on. Please see the end of the answer, and also the page it links to.

Comment: @AdathSkyderson - Yes. I said that in the answer, and linked to something that tells you that as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the submit problem can be easily solved by moving the button in the form and preventing the default behavior.

Among the submit problem, I think your code could be significantly improved by also solving the following problem: you can select both of the radio inputs: wrap them into a field-set and use the same name for them; why? it's easier to get the selected answer and can be extended to multiple inputs.

Below you have a working example with what I said.

Cheers!

```js
function Write_Text(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  let x = document.querySelector('input[name="ans"]:checked').value
  console.log(x);
  
  if (x === "false") {
      document.getElementById("text").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("text").value="";
  } else {
     document.getElementById("text").disabled =false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <h3>5- Do you know any browsers?</h3>
    <form id="dp5" action=""  method="POST" onsubmit="return Write_Text(event)">
      <fieldset>
        <input id="No" type="radio" name="ans" value="false">
        <label for="No">No </label>

        <input id="yes" type="radio" name="ans" value="true">
        <label for="yes">Yes</label>
      </fieldset>
      
      <label for="text">6 - Which?</label>
      <input id="text" type="text" name="dp5text" disabled value="">
      
      <div id="next">
        <input id="sub" type="submit" name="submit" value="Next">
      </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use event object here to prevent Default because page get refreshed onSubmit and then submit form in your function Write_Text()

```
function Write_Text(event) {
//This will prevent Default Behaviour
event.preventDefault();

let x = document.forms["dp5"]["No"].value;

if (x === "false") {
    document.getElementById("text").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("text").value="";
} else {
    document.getElementById("text").disabled =false;
}

// then submit using JS
}
```